# Non-translucent dock

Tags: unity, dock

Is there an option to have non-translucent dock when I have an application maximized? I have combed through System Settings and nothing remotely refers to that. By the way I am running Ubuntu 14.04 daily builds. Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called Ubuntu-tweak, to install you will need to add the official ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

In the tweaks tab, in the Desktop section, there is a Unity button, this opens a module that has a "Launcher opacity" option.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make the dock opacity to 1.00 when apps are maximized. It is always there. I am more referring to how Windows 7 does it with it's panel.